# Vim per file mappings

Tags: vim

I tried to put the following in my file header:

```
#!/bin/sh
# vim:set ts=2 sts=2 sw=2 expandtab:
# vim:map <leader>t :w\|:!./script.sh <cr>:
```

But Vim always complains about the `map`, saying that it's invalid. I also tried `nnoremap` with no success. What should I do to fix this (I want it in this file only)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modelines are *only* for options.

If you want this mapping only for that file, add this snippet to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
augroup ThisFile
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufRead,BufNew /path/to/file nnoremap <buffer> <leader>t :w\|:!./script.sh <cr>:
augroup END
```

*edit*

It looks like you want a mapping for executing the current file. If so, you are really chasing the wrong rabbit, here, and also crashing real hard in [the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) wall.

You can use `%` as a synonym for "the file associated with the current buffer" so, assuming your script is executable, this command would execute it:

```
:w|!./%<CR>
```

Therefore, you could simply put this generic mapping in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <leader>t :w\|!./%<CR>
```

Note 1: See `:help c_%` for the meaning of `%` and in that context.

Note 2: The bar needs to be escaped when used in a mapping, see `:help map_bar`.

Comment: Well, ok then... Any possible hack for that? For example, a way to exec the current file open or something like that?

Comment: I didn't understand your question.